# iOS 12 lost background play audio permission after play in-app video

Tags: audio, background, avaudiosession, ios12

Play audio is the main feature of my app, this is what I set:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

When audio changed, I set metadata for nowPlayingInfo:

```
[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:playingInfo];
```

It works well, audio can played in background, and lock screen will show the metadata I set.

But when I play a video in app, example a youtube link in webView. Even though the video has been closed, App will lost the background play audio permission. Lock screen not show metadata anymore, and app can't change audio in background.

This problem happened only in iOS 12, same code still work well in iOS 11. Is anyone have suggestion for this issue?